# Clipping street layer with district layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip

What I am trying to do is clip a streets layer within a district using Qgis.

They are in different CRS's and I've tried saving them into the same CRS.

I right click both of the layers and in the properties the show the same CRS.

I then go to "vector" in the menu and then to "geoprocessing tools">> clip.

I specify the layers and the result is another layer that does not show the intended results.

I've been trying to save them in the same CRS and remove the OTF projection.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Did you save under a different name, and remove the original file from the canvas? Can you add the CRS and extent of the two layers, as reported by rightclick, metadata tab?

Comment: Did you check the CRS for the exported layer, is it same as output ?